# How to use Page-Break only on upside

Tags: html, asp.net

I am using Listview to bind data from database. I need to Print 17th row on next page. So i am using page-break.

```
<tr>
    <td align="center" style="width: 1cm;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblIndex" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>' 
            Font-Bold="true" />.
        <div <%# ((Container.DataItemIndex + 1) % 18 == 0) ? "class='page-break'": "" %>>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>


<style type="text/css" media="print">
    @page
    {
        size: auto; 
        margin: 1cm;  
    }

    .page-break
    {
        float:none;
        display: block;
        page-break-before: always;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        clear: both !important;
    }
</style>
```

Here my Page-Break Applies both up and down side rows. I need only upside rows not downside.

Comment: try <STYLE TYPE='text/css'>
P.pagebreakhere {page-break-before: always}
</STYLE>

Comment: already use it. not working

Answer (score 0):

```
try this..

               <tr <%# ((Container.DataItemIndex + 1) % 18 == 0) ? "class='page-break'": "" %>>
                <td align="center" style="width: 1cm;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblIndex" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>'
                        Font-Bold="true" />.

                </td>
          </tr>
```